# The API Explorer is failing on a call to discoverAndAddAccounts

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm using the Customer Account Data API Explorer here - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CustomerAccountData

I have created an app, uploaded the certificate and can successfully call getInstitutions and getInstitutionDetails.

However, when I try to call discoverAndAddAccounts with an institution_id parameter of 12 (for E*Trade), I receive the following error:

---

Response Code
503

Response Headers
Connection : close
Content-Length : 0
Content-Type : text/plain
Date : Tue, 10 Dec 2013 01:50:28 GMT
intuit_tid : gw-687fdb97-3551-411c-816a-bb3bc997ac65
Response BodySelect body
We are currently experiencing some issues. Please try again later.

---

It just looks like there is a problem with the server but I'm not sure.  I thought it might have something to do with and MFA based request, but I do not receive the challengeSessionId or challengeNodeId from any of the prior calls.

Answer (score 0):

503 error suggests -

Database's throttler denied access to the external FI for the refresh .

There was some problem aggregating data from the external FI.

The details of the error can be found in the errorCode field of the Status entity's errorInfo structure.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0700_error_codes

Can you please try again. If you get this error again, then please raise a support ticket mentioning following details.

1. you AggCat appId
2. FI Id against which you are using AggCat APIs
3. request and response XMLs of the above API call

ApiExplorer doesn't return challengeSessionId or challengeNodeId. It is a bug which will be fixed in soon.
As an alternative, you can try to setup the sample java/.net code and set the logger in debug mode. You'll get challengeSessionId or challengeNodeId in the server console.

Thanks